# How to deploy truffle contract to dev network when using inheritance?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

I have been attempting to deploy a contract using the Truffle framework, I have recently been testing these contracts on the development network.

My contract was very large and when I attempted to deploy it to a test net, I was instructed to split it up so that the contract wouldn't exceed the gas limit. Although, bearing in mind this contract did deploy onto the development network with the default gas limit.

So I took out parts of the contract and derived another contract from the base and added the deleted sections in there. I attempted to deploy it to the development network in order to test it again, I now get the error:

```
'Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.'
```

So the steps I took was to:

1. Change my gasLimit to 100,000,000 which didn't solve it
2. Check to see if my contract is 'abstract'

   - My understanding of this is that a contract is abstract if it or its 
     parent has any functions without an implementation. Mine don't.
3. I then deleted all of the code other than the constructor from the 
   derived contract and I still get this error

I deleted the file and the deployment worked with just my base contract as before, therefore the parent contract must not have any non-implemented functions AND it still doesn't work when I attempt to derive an empty contract from it (making sure nothing was abstract in the derived contract).

4. I then split my migration files up so that the migrations happen 
   separately, still no luck.

My parent contract is around 300 lines long so no point posting it all in here - I know some people will say 'it may just be too large' however, it deployed when it was 500 lines long on the dev network and now it is only 250 lines long with a deriving contract of 275 lines long, it does not deploy.

The error:

```
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
Replacing ERC20Token...
 ... 0xcae613274de1aa278e7ae5d1239f43445132a417d98765a4f227ea2439c9e4fc
 ERC20Token: 0xeec918d74c746167564401103096d45bbd494b74
 Replacing Crowdsale...
 ... 0x0ffc7291d84289c1391a81ed9f76d1e165285e3a3eadc065732aa288ea049b3a
 Crowdsale: 0x0d8cc4b8d15d4c3ef1d70af0071376fb26b5669b
 Saving successful migration to network...
 ... 0x7f351d76f61f7b801913f59b808688a2567b64933cdfdcf78bb18b0bf4e4ff69
 Saving artifacts...
 Running migration: 3_more_deployed_contracts.js
   Deploying StagedSale...
   ... 0x216136bb24d317b140a247f10ec4d6791559739111a85932133cd4a66b12a1d9
 Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful 
 transactions manually.
 Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas 
 amount.
at Object.callback 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329221:46)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:39618:25
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331159:9
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:175492:11
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329855:7)
```

My base contract is too large to post, and it deploys fine on its own meaning its not abstract.

My derived contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./Crowdsale.sol";

contract StagedSale is Crowdsale {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

   /*
    * Setup the contract and transfer ownership to appropriate beneficiary
    */
    function StagedSale
    ( 
        uint256 _stage1Duration, 
        uint256 _stage2Duration
    ) public {
        uint256 stage1duration = _stage1Duration.mul(1 minutes);
        uint256 stage2duration = _stage2Duration.mul(1 minutes);
    }
```

My migration file for the derived contract:

```
var StagedSale = artifacts.require("./StagedSale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  const stage1Duration = 1;
  const stage2Duration = 1;

  deployer.deploy(StagedSale, stage1Duration, stage2Duration);
};
```

I have posted this question here as I fear this may be a common issue with Truffle deployment.

To conclude, I don't believe this has anything to do with the actual gas limits and is instead, failing for some unknown reason and printing this error message anyway.

Comment: I would tend to take the error message at face value. What does web3.eth.estimateGas() tell you? Take a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/when-i-am-deploying-contract-getting-the-error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-s

Comment: I've seen that question and it cant be that reason, if you note the start of the question my contract deployed just fine on the development network with 500+ lines in it. I then tried to deploy it to a test net and THEN it said it was too large. 

So I split the contracts down into one base contract of 300 lines and started off with a inherited contract of around 30 lines before adding more functions in. 

I now get this error when trying to deploy to the development server so I cant even test what it does, again it did work with my previous 500+ line contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a fix to this, basically if you are inheriting from a base contract, you must deploy the base contract within the inherited contracts constructor like so:

OLD VERSION:

Simply deployed the base, then deployed the inheriting contract with a reference to 'is Crowdsale' in class name

```
  deployer.deploy(ERC20Token, initialAmount, tokenName, decimalUnits,tokenSymbol).then(function() {
    return deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, softCap, hardCap, etherCostOfEachToken, sendFundsTo, toChecksumAddress(ERC20Token.address), durationInMinutes);
  });

deployer.deploy(FinalizableSale);
```

NEW VERSION

Only deploy the inheriting contract and create a new instance of base within that constructor

```
  deployer.deploy(ERC20Token, initialAmount, tokenName, decimalUnits,tokenSymbol).then(function() {
    return deployer.deploy(Finalizable, softCap, hardCap, etherCostOfEachToken, sendFundsTo, toChecksumAddress(ERC20Token.address), durationInMinutes);
  });
```

FINALIZABLE CONSTRUCTOR:

```
function FinalizableSale(uint256 _fundingGoalInEthers, uint256 _fundingLimitInEthers,  uint256 _etherCostOfEachToken, address _sendFundsTo, address _tokenAddress, uint256 _durationInMinutes)
    Crowdsale(_fundingGoalInEthers, _fundingLimitInEthers, _etherCostOfEachToken, _sendFundsTo, _tokenAddress, _durationInMinutes)
{
   //do something
}
```

NOTE: That the base contract is initialised BEFORE the opening brackets to the constructor function.

I no longer get the 'out of gas' error and my contract runs as before.