# Why am I getting exceeds gas limit error when I specify the exact gas limit?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am deploying a contract using truffle, and when I specify the gas limit as the gas I want to use for the transaction I always get the exceeds gas limit error. Why does this happen?

edit
What I am trying to do is deploy the crypto kitties KittyCore.sol contract to my local devnet. I am using truffle to deploy it.

From another page, [How to deploy truffle contract to dev network when using inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893129/how-to-deploy-truffle-contract-to-dev-network-when-using-inheritance?rq=1), I found that since there is a contract hierarchy, I need to deploy my contracts in order. I used this technique, and I am able to deploy 4 out of 7 contracts, with the fifth, KittyAuction, giving the following error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Posted below is my truffle deployer script

```
var KittyCore = artifacts.require("KittyCore");
var KittyMinting = artifacts.require("KittyMinting");
var KittyAuction = artifacts.require("KittyAuction");
var KittyBreeding = artifacts.require("KittyBreeding");
var KittyOwnership = artifacts.require("KittyOwnership");
var KittyBase = artifacts.require("KittyBase");
var KittyAccessControl = artifacts.require("KittyAccessControl");
var SaleClockAuction = artifacts.require("SaleClockAuction");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(KittyAccessControl).then(function () {
        return deployer.deploy(KittyBase).then(function () {
            return deployer.deploy(KittyOwnership).then(function () {
                return deployer.deploy(KittyBreeding).then(function () {
                    return deployer.deploy(KittyAuction, {
                        gas: 400000
                    }).then(function () {
                        return deployer.deploy(KittyMinting).then(function () {
                            return deployer.deploy(KittyCore);
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    });
};
```

My gas limit is set to 18000000000. This gas number is produced by running the following function on the actual contract that fails to deploy

```
var gasPrice;
KittyAuction.web3.eth.getGasPrice(function (error, result) {
    gasPrice = Number(result);
    console.log(gasPrice);
})
```

I have been fiddling with this number and nothing seems to work.

Comment: What's the smallest gas limit you can set and still have the transaction succeed?

Comment: Also, edit your question to include your contract code, the gas limit you're specifying, and how you came up with that number.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy the cryptokitties main contract to my local devnet. It's a lot of quote to post but it is freely available and I have not made any changes except adding the payable keyword to the Constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was able to deploy it. What I did was reset my blockchain, and set gasLimit to 0x8000000 and gave each contract that was troublesome a gas value of 0x7000000, and it deployed. Funny thing though, it wouldnt deploy again. I guess the gasLimit adjusted after a few blocks were mined because I got an error saying I was over the limit